# select data from two tables with where condition in php mysql

Tags: mysql

**Table 1**

```
Workid --- Workname --- Workdetails

w001 --- workname1 --- detail1

w002 --- workname2 --- detail2
```

**Table 2**

```
Id --- Workid --- Workstartdatetime --- Workstopdate_time

T001 --- w001 --- 2016-12-31 10:00:00 --- 2016-12-31 18:00:00

T001 --- w002 --- 2016-12-30 10:00:00 --- 2016-12-30 18:00:00
```

Table1 and Table2 Workid are same.

I am taking 2 inputs from user:

```
**$Workstartdatetime = "2016-12-31 12:00:00";**
```

and

```
**$Workstopdate_time = "2016-12-31 17:00:00";**
```

My query is, if the user provided `$Workstartdatetime` and `$Workstopdatetime` is not in between the table 2 `Workstartdatetime` and `Workstopdatetime Table1 Workid` should display.

For example we already assigned values to the variable so only `workid w002` should display.

How to write a query for this in PHP

Thank you

Comment: Yes, Not in between

Comment: elaborate in details else paste the code

Comment: looking for sql query or how to do it in php ?

Comment: how to do it in php

Comment: Try to format your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN`, it will join the tables by the key you provide and you can make the condition on the `WHERE` in your case you want a valid date between the user input dates.

I've created a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f40e/5)** for you.

More information about **[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)**.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT
  t1.workid
FROM
 table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
ON
  t1.workid = t2.workid
WHERE
  t2.Workstartdatetime > '".$$Workstartdatetime."' 
AND 
  t2.Workstopdate_time < '".$Workstopdate_time."'
```